# how to upgrade designation in php data

Tags: php

i am working with a mlm company's site where i hv to design to upgrade the status of member from  one step to higher after adding 5 members every member has to upgrade to upper level.i have some code but i dont know how to call this function

here is my code:-

```
function CheckAndUpgradeDesignation($username,$des)
    {
    if($des=='Crown')
    return;
    $q="SELECT introducer_id FROM members WHERE user_id='$username'";
    $rs=mysql_query($q);
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $id=$r['introducer_id'];
    $q="SELECT count(*) as total from members WHERE introducer_id='$id' AND designation='$des'";
        $rs1=mysql_query($q);
    $r1=mysql_fetch_array($rs1);
    $t=$r1['total'];
    if($t==5)
    {
    if($des=="VIP")
       $des1="Journey";
       else
        if($des=="Journey")
       $des1="Executive";
       else
        if($des=="Executive")
       $des1="DreamFlight";
       else
        if($des=="DreamFlight")
       $des1="Safari";
       else
        if($des=="Safari")
       $des1="GoldRace";
       else
        if($des=="GoldRace")
       $des1="RoyalRace";
       else
        if($des=="RoyalRace")
       $des1="Aashiyana";
       else
        if($des=="Aashiyana")
       $des1="Crown";
       $q="UPDATE members SET designation='$des1' WHERE user_id='$id'";
       mysql_query($q);
       CheckAndUpgradeDesignation($id,$des1);
       }
}
```

pls check anyone is this code looks right or need some change...............if u hv some question ask me

Comment: The code is not good , line 5 sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You would call the function like this: `CheckAndUpgradeDesignation('1', 'GoldRace');`

Also you might rename the function parameter `$username` to `$userid`, because the SQL uses `user_id`.

Please escape the values inserted into the SQL statment properly to avoid injections.

Maybe refactor the function into 3 functions:

1. fetchDesignation($user_id) - which returns the designation for a user_id
2. raiseDesignation($des) - which is the logic part to level up and returns the new level or false
3. updateDesignation($user_id, $des) - which inserts the new level into the db

This suggestions is a bit more flexible, but it depends on the use case.
It allows testing the logic for raiseDesignation() in a seperate unit-test, without touching the db. Also fetching the designation for a user_id is now seperate.

Answer (score 0):

I could refactor your code separating some important tasks. In the other hand, I recommend you don't try to write large functions with lot of code, because it could be no easy to understand.

```
 <?php

function CheckAndUpgradeDesignation($userId, $designation)
{
    if ($designation == 'Crown') {
        return;
    }

    $introducerId = GetIntroducerIdByUserId($userId);
    $memberTotal = GetTotalOfMembersByIntroducerIdAndDesignationId($introducerId, $designation);

    if ($memberTotal == 5) {
        $designationValue = VerifyDesignation($designation);
        UpdateDesignation($designationValue, $introducerId);
        CheckAndUpgradeDesignation($introducerId, $designationValue);
    }
}

function VerifyDesignation($designation)
{
    $designationList = array(
        'VIP' => 'Journey',
        'Journey' => 'Executive',
        'Executive' => 'DreamFlight',
        'DreamFlight' => 'Safari',
        'Safari' => 'GoldRace',
        'GoldRace' => 'RoyalRace',
        'RoyalRace' => 'Aashiyana',
        'Aashiyana' => 'Crown'
    );

    if (key_exists($designation, $designationList)) {
        return $designationList[$designation];
    }

    return null;
}

function GetIntroducerIdByUserId($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT introducer_id FROM members WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $response = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    return $response['introducer_id'];
}

function GetTotalOfMembersByIntroducerIdAndDesignationId($introducerId, $designation)
{
    $query = "SELECT count(*) as total from members WHERE introducer_id='$introducerId' AND designation = '$designation'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $response = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    return $response['total'];
}

function UpdateDesignation($designationValue, $introducerId)
{
    $query = "UPDATE members SET designation='$designationValue' WHERE user_id = '$introducerId'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Also check VerifyDesignation function it could be more efficient instead use multiple if statements.

I hope it can help you.